# Delay in websocket communication using Autobahn Python and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, html, websocket, autobahn

Here is what I am working with:

webserver.py:

```
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log

from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, \
                               WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                               listenWS


class EchoServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

   def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
      print "sending echo:", msg
      self.sendMessage(msg, binary)


if __name__ == '__main__':

   log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

   factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000", debug = False)
   factory.protocol = EchoServerProtocol
   listenWS(factory)

   reactor.run()
```

background.js:

```
function updateCookies(info) {
    send();
    console.log(info.cookie.domain);
}

function send() {
    msg = "TEST";
    sock.send(msg);
};

var sock = null;
sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");
console.log("Websocket created...");

sock.onopen = function() {
    console.log("connected to server");
    sock.send("CONNECTED TO YOU");
}

sock.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("connection closed (" + e.code + ")");
}

sock.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("message received: " + e.data);
}

chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(updateCookies);
```

Now, upon running webserver.py and running background.js, nothing happens. The client see's no echo and the server doesn't report any connections or messages. However, if I reload background.js, all the sudden the previous message of "CONNECTED TO YOU" is shown by the server. Reloading again produces the same effect, showing the delayed "CONNECTED TO YOU" message. I've tried running sock.close() after sending the message, but that still produces nothing. I'm really confused at what is causing this random delay. Leaving the server running for 10 - 15 minutes also produces nothing, I must manually refresh the page before I see any messages. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried the WS echo example https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/echo ?

Comment: Yes, it had the exact same effect.

Comment: Try disabling any desktop firewalls and the like. Try running the server on same machine as browser. Try Chrome vs Firefox. The above example does work .. the issue must stem from your network/firewall environment ..